# TTF Font not being displayed when using @Font-Family

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to add a Font to a website im making using [@Font-Face](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp) but its not working. I did it exactly like in the link above, but its not working.

My Code:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 04B;
    src: url("04b.ttf") format('truetype');
    
}

table {
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
 font-size:40px;
    font-family: 04B;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

h1 {
 text-align:center;
 font-size:50px;
    font-family: 04B;
}
```

```html
<h1>Problem is that the font displays exactly like it does in this demo window but shouldnt since I added a font</h1>
```

Also the font im trying to use is a TTF font which I got [from here.](http://www.dafont.com/de/04b-30.font) The font is also located in the same directory as the CSS file so I think that should be totally fine

I tried testing it in Edge, IE and Chrome and its always the same...

Am I just being really stupid and missing something?

Comment: You should make a proper kit - http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: if ur css is in a different directory from the root directory where you're html files are then try this 
src: url(../your_css_folder/04b.ttf); without the double quotes.
else src: url(../04b.ttf);

Comment: The CSS and HTML files are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a kit like Pangloss suggested in the comments seems to have fixed it. Im still not sure what I did wrong, but following the exact instructions of the Kit worked perfectly :D