# TTF fonts don't display in the browser when bundling with webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, fonts

I'm trying to bundle a static webpage with webpack. npm run build is working just fine with all of the javascript, sass, and font and image assets being compressed and sent to the dist file. The problem is the browser doesn't display my fonts. This is what my webpack config file looks like

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './public/app.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(scss)$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'sass-loader'
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
      use: [
        { loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            useRelativePath: true,
            outputPath: 'assets/images'
          } 
        }
      ]
    },
       {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            useRelativePath: true,
            outputPath: 'assets/fonts'
          } 
        }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried using font loader, I've tried using url loader, I've tried using loaders specifically for ttf, i.e. ttf-loader. I've tried various permutations on the code quoted above [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188906/ttf-font-not-being-displayed-when-using-font-family) , I've tried adding sourceMap=true to sass loader. I've tried converting my fonts to other formats but no luck.

My guess is that there's something wrong with the way I've imported the fonts in my Sass file, since there's nothing ostensibly wrong when I build.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Oswald-Light";
  src: url("../assets/fonts/Oswald-Light.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("../assets/fonts/Oswald-Light.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Oswald-Regular";
  src: url("../assets/fonts/Oswald-Regular.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("../assets/fonts/Oswald-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato";
  src: url("../assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("../assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

Is there anything glaringly obviously wrong with any of the above code?

Comment: Hard to tell without setting up an webpack environment to test your code. Comparing your code to the webpack docs (https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-fonts) I see nothing wrong about it.

Comment: I know that's what was so head bangingly frustrating about it. I have a work around now though.

Answer (score -2):

For anyone else struggling to do this in the future - seen a few threads asking similar questions - consider using Google Fonts and just inserting a link tag in the head.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: In spite of the down vote this actually works and saves increasing the size of your webpack bundle with the size of locally served font files.